# how to share message to google plus without the requisite of "Google Plus" app installed in device

Tags: android, google-plus

I have integrated the google plus using both  Auth 2.0 & using native Share(+1) Button as on [Google Plus Developers](https://developers.google.com/+/). The code is working fine (doing SignIn, fetching profile and search friends).

But I now want to share text on google plus.

By the second way Of using share button as suggested on google plus android developers is working good in case of share message.

**But I want to share message to google plus of user without using intent or ShareCompat etc.
Is there any way as this all need that Google Plus app must be installed in device...?**

*Is There any way to do that without the need of google plus app installing in device...?*

Regards,

Arpit

Comment: if u get answer to ur question from my Posted answer please accept it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google API do not allow write access like facebook and twitter api. You must have google application installed.

Here they say:

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public
>   data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Google plus [API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) provides read only access for now.

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitly share a link using the path to the Google+ share form.  For example:

https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com

Will share a link to Stack Overflow.